# Graph laplacian: second smallest eigenvalue

Tags: spectral-graph-theory, graph-laplacian

Let $G$ be a weighted undirected graph with vertex set $V$ and weight matrix $W$.
Given $S\subset V$, we define
$$cut(S,S^c):=\sum_{i\in S,j\in S^c} w_{ij}$$
Let $L$ be the graph Laplacian of $G$. It is well known that the second smallest eigenvalue $\lambda_2(L)$ is linked to the existence of a of a cut in $V$; in particular, [it has been proved that](https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.05627)
$$\text{min}_{S\subset V} \frac{cut(S,S^c)|V|}{|S^c||S|}\ge \lambda_2(L).$$
**Do there exists any result that bounds this eigenvalue from the below?**

$$\lambda_2(L)\ge ...$$
(even in some special cases)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second smallest eigenvalue $\lambda_2$ is closely related to the isoperimetric constant of a graph. A general result is that if a graph $G$ has maximal degree $d$ and isoperimetric constant $iso(G)$, then we have
$$iso(G) \leq \sqrt{2d\lambda_2}.$$

See Theorem 11.15, Bogdan Nica, *A Brief Introduction to Spectral Graph Theory*. The theorem is originally from this paper: https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1984-284-02/S0002-9947-1984-0743744-X/S0002-9947-1984-0743744-X.pdf.